# I am trying to use jQuery with Spring MVC to get "bookid" from the databse but i am getting error alert every time

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp

Hi there I am using jQuery with Spring MVC to get the book_id from the database but I am getting error alert every time

I have used jQuery ajax() method and defined all the parameters properly like url and in Controller i have used all proper annotations but failed to get the output.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bookId").keypress(function () {
                    var bookid = $(this).val();
                    alert($(this).val());
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "getBookQuantity.htm",
                            data: {
                            bookid : bookid
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (json) {
                                if (json !== null) {
                                    alert(json);
                                }
                            },       
                            error: function (e) {
                                alert("Some error occured while getting book id list");
                            }      
                });
            });
        });
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBookQuantity.htm")
 @ResponseBody
 public String getBookQuantity(@RequestParam(value = "bookid", defaultValue = "0") int bookid) {
    System.out.println("bookid======="+bookid);
    int quantity = this.bookService.checkBookQuantity(bookid);

    String json = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    json = gson.toJson(quantity);
    return json;
}
```

Getting error alert every time

Comment: What's the actual error?  What does `e` contain in your error callback function?  What is the response from the server?

Comment: random but are you making an ajax request on every keypress? unless there is a specific reason for making that many requests you might want to rig up a submit button and then also make sure to check your network tab in your devtools to make sure the right data is going through. Also I believe the default http request is `GET` for `$.ajax()`, so in your ajax set `type: 'POST'`

Comment: Did you check if it's going to your controller by putting a breakpoint? Also, try printing value of `e` on console using `console.log(e)` to understand more about error.

Comment: As a note, a huge feature of Spring is that you don't have to manually deal with JSON. Just `return quantity` and you should be fine.